# How to read Error messages in Swift 2.1?

Tags: swift, error-handling

I don't know how to read error messages in Swift 2.1. They are very complicated. I know Error messages in java, php and other languages which are much better to read and understand..

What is the best way, to understand this message?

```
unexpected nil window in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent, _windowServerHitTestWindow: <UIClassicWindow: 0x13de0e270; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); userInteractionEnabled = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x13de13fd0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x13de0ec60>>
```

I don't want to write a new Question on stackoverflow because of every error message.

Comment: can you please put some code where you are getting this error?

Comment: Yes, please add the chunk of code that is causing the error. Also, is this the only error message you got?